# Editing Local Storage code to add unique ID to each element

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a piece of Local Storage functionality based on this example:

https://scriptscodes.com/codes/CrocoDillon/pIlKB/preview/index.html

CSS:

```
/* https://scriptscodes.com/codes/CrocoDillon/pIlKB/preview/index.html */
.list li{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.list li:before,.list li.fav:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f08a";
    color:white;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size:14px;
}

.list li:hover:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f004";
    color:white;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size:14px;
}

.list li.fav:hover:before,.list li.fav:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content:"\f004";
    color:red;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="list" style="background:#ccc; padding:20px;">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li id="petty">petty</li>
        <li id="bedfordshire">bedfordshire</li>
        <li id="rearing">rearing</li>
        <li id="jane">jane</li>
        <li id="furore">furore</li>                         
    </ul>
</div>
```

Then I can add each item to local storage with this:

JS:

```
var favorites =   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];

document.querySelector('.list').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var id = e.target.id,
        item = e.target,
        index = favorites.indexOf(id);
    if (!id) return;
    if (index == -1) {
        favorites.push(id);
        item.className = 'fav';
    } else {
        favorites.splice(index, 1);
        item.className = '';
    }
    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
});
```

A test page using this code is here: https://jimpix.co.uk/testing/test3.asp

So the "favorites" array looks like this:

```
favorites:"["petty","rearing","jane"]"
```

I need to work out how to edit the JS so that each element is given a unique ID, so the array looks like this:

```
favorites:"[{"id":"1","name":"petty"},{"id":"2","name":"rearing"},{"id":"3","name":"jane"}]"
```

Is it possible to do that?

I'd prefer not to use jQuery as I'd have to rewrite the JS used in this code, and also on another page where I output the local storage data.

Thanks

Comment: I can't see the problem just push `favorites.push({ id: 1, name: "petty" }` into your array and stringify it afterwards? For a unique Id take the index of the for loop or try something like this: `Math.floor(window.performance.now() * 1000)`

Comment: Thanks - that worked. I have one more question - can you see how I can then check through the array to see if that item / value exists in the array, as the existing `index = favorites.indexOf(id);` line always returns `-1` each time I click a list item - it seems that inserting the next into a "name" element / key means the indexOf can't find it any more?

Comment: I wrote an answer for both requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the problem just push `favorites.push({ id: 1, name: "petty" }` into your array and stringify it afterwards? For a unique Id take the index of the for loop or try something like this: `Math.floor(window.performance.now() * 1000)`

For finding if an element is in the array just do the following:

```
function isIdInArray(id) { // param id is the id youre looking for in the array
    var isInArray = false;
    favorites.forEach(function(favorite){
        if(favorite.id === id){
            isInArray = true;
        }
    });
    return isInArray;
}
```

To clarify if you make `index = favorites.indexOf(id);` this wil search a string for a string.
Eg. `"apple".indexOf("ple");` will return 2 because it found "ple" starting in the string at position 2. If the string does not contain the searched string Eg: `"apple.indexOf("tomato");` the return value will be -1. You can't execute indexOf on an array. You could search your stringified array for the index value with `indexOf()` but i would not reccomend you to do that.